# How do I add a legend to an ASP.NET 3.5 chart control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, charts

Is there a way to add a legend to the chart it creates? I have created a line chart and by default it has created different colors for the different y - axis data. I would like a legend on the side the displays what data goes with which line color.

Thank You.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your chart control can create a legend using the data series names simply by adding the following line:

```
chart.Legends.Add(new Legend("Default") { Docking = Docking.Right});
```