# Extra legend Item in ASP.Net Pie Chart Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, charts, pie-chart

I am using MS Pie Chart Control in ASP.Net.Here is the markup of my chart control in ASPX -

```
 <asp:Chart runat="server" ID="chartX" CssClass="chart" Width="420px" Height="500px" ImageType="Jpeg">
    <Series></Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
    <Legends>
        <asp:Legend Docking="Bottom" Alignment="Center" Font="Calibri"></asp:Legend>
    </Legends>
 </asp:Chart>
```

Here is the code to populate chart control in ASPX.vb -

```
Dim table As DataTable = PopulateData()
Dim dv As DataView = New DataView(table, "Count > 0", "", DataViewRowState.OriginalRows)

Dim series As String = r("Name").ToString()
chartX.Series.Add(series)
chartX.Series(series).ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Pie
chartX.Series(series).XValueMember = "Name"
chartX.Series(series).YValueMembers = "Count"
chartX.ChartAreas(0).Area3DStyle.Enable3D = True
chartX.Series(series).Label = "#VALX" & Environment.NewLine & "(#PERCENT)"
chartX.Series(series)("PieLabelStyle") = "Disabled"

chartX.DataSource = dv
chartX.DataBind()
```

The above code works fine. I have a specific situation where I want to display an extra legend item as the SUM of all items present on the pie chart.

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280904/how-do-i-add-a-legend-to-an-asp-net-3-5-chart-control

Comment: @TasosK.This didn't help :(